# I am getting performance issue with this aggregation pipeline?This almost takes 20 sec to give response of 30000 records

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mern

The aggregation pipeline taking almost 20 to 25 sec to execute and give response.But inspite of creating indexes it is still taking time 20 to 22 sec.I guess these lookups takes more time ,Byt why and how I can solve this issue?
Note:It fetches mostly 30400 records. My MongoDB version is 5.0.20…

**I have created Indexes,**

```
createdAt: 1
 businessUnitId: 1
 commodityId: 1
 commodityVariantId: 1
 createdBy: 1
 isDeleted: 1
isSLCMQcInspection: 1
commodityDetail.CIDNumber_text
```

**Aggregation pipeline:**

```
async getQCResultSLcm(
    filters: GetAllQcInspectionWithFilterSlcmDto,
    businessUnitId: string,
  ) {
    let startDateQuery = {};
    let endDateQuery = {};
    let commoditySearchQuery = {};
    let variantSearchQuery = {};
    const statusQuery = {};
    let cidNumberSearchQuery = {};
    let lotNoSearchQuery = {};
    const businessUnitFilterQuery = {};
    let generalSearchQuery = {};

    if (filters.startDate) {
      startDateQuery = {
        $expr: {
          $gte: [
            '$createdAt',
            {
              $dateFromString: {
                dateString: filters.startDate,
                timezone: '+05:30',
                format: '%m-%d-%Y',
              },
            },
          ],
        },
      };
    }

    if (filters.endDate) {
      endDateQuery = {
        $expr: {
          $lt: [
            '$createdAt',
            {
              $dateAdd: {
                startDate: {
                  $dateFromString: {
                    dateString: filters.endDate,
                    timezone: '+05:30',
                    format: '%m-%d-%Y',
                  },
                },
                unit: 'day',
                amount: 1,
              },
            },
          ],
        },
      };
    }

    // if (filters.startDate) {
    //   startDateQuery = { createdAt: { $gte: DateTime.fromFormat(filters.startDate, "MM-dd-yyyy").setZone("+05:30").toJSDate() } }
    // }
    // if (filters.endDate) {
    //   endDateQuery = { createdAt: { $lt: DateTime.fromFormat(filters.startDate, "MM-dd-yyyy").plus({ days: 1 }).setZone("+05:30").toJSDate() } }
    // }

    if (filters.searchByCommodity) {
      commoditySearchQuery = {
        'commodityData.name': {
          $regex: `${filters.searchByCommodity}`,
          $options: 'i',
        },
      };
    }
    if (filters.searchByVariant) {
      variantSearchQuery = {
        'commodityVariantData.name': {
          $regex: `${filters.searchByVariant}`,
          $options: 'i',
        },
      };
    }

    if (filters.searchByStatus) {
      statusQuery['status'] = filters.searchByStatus;
    }

    if (filters.searchByCIDNumber) {
      cidNumberSearchQuery = {
        $or: [
          {
            'commodityDetail.CIDNumber': {
              $regex: `${filters.searchByCIDNumber}`,
              $options: 'i',
            },
          },
          // {
          //   'businessUnitData.name': {
          //     $regex: `${filters.searchByCIDNumber}`,
          //     $options: 'i',
          //   },
          // },
          // {
          //   'commodityDetail.LOTNumber': {
          //     $regex: `${filters.searchByLotNo}`,
          //     $options: 'i',
          //   },
          // },
          // {
          //   'qcId': {
          //     $regex: `${filters.searchByCIDNumber}`,
          //     $options: 'i',
          //   },
          // },
        ],
      };
    }
    if (filters.searchByLotNo) {
      lotNoSearchQuery = {
        $or: [
          {
            'commodityDetail.LOTNumber': {
              $regex: `${filters.searchByLotNo}`,
              $options: 'i',
            },
          },
        ],
      };
    }
    if (filters.searchByGeneralSearch) {
      generalSearchQuery = {
        $or: [
          {
            qcId: {
              $regex: `${filters.searchByGeneralSearch}`,
              $options: 'i',
            },
          },
          {
            'businessUnitData.name': {
              $regex: `${filters.searchByGeneralSearch}`,
              $options: 'i',
            },
          },
          {
            'userData.name': {
              $regex: `${filters.searchByGeneralSearch}`,
              $options: 'i',
            },
          },
        ],
      };
    }

    if (businessUnitId) {
      businessUnitFilterQuery['businessUnitId'] = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(
        businessUnitId,
      );
    }
    // const startTime = Date.now();
    const result = await this.qcInspectionModel.aggregate([
      {
        $match: {
          $and: [
            startDateQuery,
            endDateQuery,
            statusQuery,
            businessUnitFilterQuery,
            { isDeleted: false },
            { isSLCMQcInspection: true },
          ],
        },
      },
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: 'mastercommodities',
          localField: 'commodityId',
          pipeline: [
            {
              $project: {
                name: 1,
              },
            },
          ],
          foreignField: '_id',
          as: 'commodityData',
        },
      },
      {
        $unwind: '$commodityData',
      },
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: 'commodityvariants',
          localField: 'commodityVariantId',
          pipeline: [
            {
              $project: {
                name: 1,
              },
            },
          ],
          foreignField: '_id',
          as: 'commodityVariantData',
        },
      },
      {
        $unwind: '$commodityVariantData',
      },
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: 'businessunits',
          localField: 'businessUnitId',
          pipeline: [
            {
              $lookup: {
                from: 'businesses',
                localField: 'businessId',
                foreignField: '_id',
                as: 'businessClientName',
              },
            },
            {
              $unwind: '$businessClientName',
            },
            {
              $project: {
                name: 1,
                businessClientName: '$businessClientName.displayName',
              },
            },
          ],
          foreignField: '_id',
          as: 'businessUnitData',
        },
      },
      {
        $unwind: {
          path: '$businessUnitData',
          preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true,
        },
      },
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: 'users',
          localField: 'createdBy',
          foreignField: '_id',
          as: 'userData',
          pipeline: [
            {
              $project: {
                firstName: 1,
                lastName: 1,
                _id: 0,
                name: { $concat: ['$firstName', ' ', '$lastName'] },
              },
            },
          ],
        },
      },
      {
        $unwind: {
          path: '$userData',
          preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true,
        },
      },
      {
        $match: {
          $and: [
            commoditySearchQuery,
            variantSearchQuery,
            generalSearchQuery,
            cidNumberSearchQuery,
            lotNoSearchQuery
          ],
        },
      },
      {
        $sort: {
          createdAt:
            filters.sortOrder && filters.sortOrder != SortOrder.Ascending
              ? SortOrder.Descending
              : SortOrder.Ascending,
        },
      },
      {
        $project: {
          _id: 1,
          status: 1,
          commodityData: 1,
          commodityDetail: 1,
          commodityVariantData: 1,
          createdAt: 1,
          qcId: 1,
          sampleName: 1,
          businessUnitData: 1,
          userData: 1,
          location: 1,
          middlewareStatus: 1,
        },
      },
      {
        $facet: {
          records: [
            { $skip: (filters.pageNumber - 1) * filters.count },
            { $limit: filters.count * 1 },
          ],
          total: [{ $count: 'count' }],
        },
      }
    ]);
    // const endTime = Date.now();
    // const executionTimeMs = endTime - startTime;
    // console.log('Execution time:', executionTimeMs, 'ms');
    return result;
  }
```

**explain() result,**

```
{
  explainVersion: '1',
  stages: [
    {
      '$cursor': [Object],
      nReturned: 30104,
      executionTimeMillisEstimate: 4925
    },
    {
      '$lookup': [Object],
      totalDocsExamined: 30103,
      totalKeysExamined: 30103,
      collectionScans: 0,
      indexesUsed: [Array],
      nReturned: 30103,
      executionTimeMillisEstimate: 8556
    },
    {
      '$lookup': [Object],
      totalDocsExamined: 30103,
      totalKeysExamined: 30103,
      collectionScans: 0,
      indexesUsed: [Array],
      nReturned: 30103,
      executionTimeMillisEstimate: 11726
    },
    {
      '$lookup': [Object],
      totalDocsExamined: 30103,
      totalKeysExamined: 30103,
      collectionScans: 0,
      indexesUsed: [Array],
      nReturned: 30103,
      executionTimeMillisEstimate: 18457
    },
    {
      '$lookup': [Object],
      totalDocsExamined: 30103,
      totalKeysExamined: 30103,
      collectionScans: 0,
      indexesUsed: [Array],
      nReturned: 30103,
      executionTimeMillisEstimate: 23009
    },
    {
      '$sort': [Object],
      totalDataSizeSortedBytesEstimate: 55157785,
      usedDisk: false,
      nReturned: 30103,
      executionTimeMillisEstimate: 23014
    },
    {
      '$project': [Object],
      nReturned: 30103,
      executionTimeMillisEstimate: 23154
    },
    {
      '$facet': [Object],
      nReturned: 1,
      executionTimeMillisEstimate: 23232
    }
  ],
  serverInfo: {
    host: '********',
    port: ****,
    version: '5.0.20',
    gitVersion: '2cd626d8148120319d7dca5824e760fe220cb0de'
  },
  serverParameters: {
    internalQueryFacetBufferSizeBytes: 104857600,
    internalQueryFacetMaxOutputDocSizeBytes: 104857600,
    internalLookupStageIntermediateDocumentMaxSizeBytes: 104857600,
    internalDocumentSourceGroupMaxMemoryBytes: 104857600,
    internalQueryMaxBlockingSortMemoryUsageBytes: 104857600,
    internalQueryProhibitBlockingMergeOnMongoS: 0,
    internalQueryMaxAddToSetBytes: 104857600,
    internalDocumentSourceSetWindowFieldsMaxMemoryBytes: 104857600
  },
  command: {
    aggregate: 'qcinspections',
    pipeline: [
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object]
    ],
    cursor: {},
    '$db': '*******-test'
  },
  ok: 1,
  '$clusterTime': {
    clusterTime: new Timestamp({ t: 1694197055, i: 1 }),
    signature: {
     
  },
  operationTime: new Timestamp({ t: 1694197055, i: 1 })
}
```

Any suggestion,any solution is accepted.... you can share....Thank you..

Comment: If you are talking about 30400 records, even with indexes, your kind of aggregation is going to take a long time.... 20-25 seconds is a norm since it's going to read through all the documents. You should opt to lessen the records that needs to be searched in your first $match.

Comment: No,this is not normal this impacts user experience...

Comment: Look at your explain, you are doing many things with 30k records, and look at your $lookup and its executionTimeMillisEstimate. The first 4 seconds come from your match, your third lookup took 6 seconds and then subsequently 5 seconds. There's too many records to examined. You need to narrow down your search before hitting these expensive lookups

Comment: Agree with what @SomeoneSpecial said, having so many lookups doesn't seem a good schema design for NoSQL database. You may want to check out how to denormalize your schema as some of your lookups seemingly just want to get a field from other collection. [This](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design) could be a starting point to learn more.

Comment: Yes, you guys may be correct, but schema redesign for ongoing or completed projects can be very time-consuming. In a large-scale project, that collection may already be used in various places separately. So, is there any other way? I am also facing the same issue.

Comment: What I did, for ongoing projects with past and future data, is to add additional fields to each document permanently, to avoid doing additional lookups. Also, using $regex is slow, try using text search?